# Allow expansion of images from within questions or answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, images, android-app

Its pretty hard to read the text within an image at that size. How about image expansion within the app?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is live as of the newest app update, 0.1.19.