# Center and zoom in on the expanded image in image view

Tags: feature-request, images, android-app

[On clicking on an image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194724/200868), the expanded image is shown as:

[image]

The image should be centered and zoomed in to at least fill the space available.

Version: 0.1.19